# CloudKit Notifications not delivered to all devices

Tags: ios, push-notification, cloudkit, ckquery

I have the problem that CloudKit notifications are not delivered to all devices when my app was started on the device. However, everything works fine if the app has been started from XCode.

In specific:

- Device A saves a record
- On the server, there is a CKQuerySubscription that fires a notification on record change
- According to the server log, this notification gets pushed
- However, device B will only receive the notification if the app got started from XCode. It will not if it got started from
  the home screen.
- To make it perfect: If I save a record on device B (no matter
  if the app got started from Xcode or home screen), device A will always receive the notification.

Would be glad to receive any hint notifications ;-)
Udo

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm having the same issue. I receive notifications just fine running from Xcode, but not if I launch my app from the Springboard screen.

Comment: Not yet, sorry. Turning on the background modes for the app (which is a commonly used hint for this issue) did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work for me by enabling background Remote notifications and Background fetch in the Capabilities / Background Modes area in Xcode. Now my app can receive CloudKit notifications while not running from Xcode.